# Pandas read_csv: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Suppose I have a file test.csv which looks like this:

```
A,B,C
Hello,Hi,1
```

I'm attempting to read this into a Pandas dataframe:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
col_types = {'A': str, 'B': str, 'C': int}
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=cols, dtype=col_types)
```

This produces the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that is the error?

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Yep, it's definitely the error I'm getting. I'm using '0.12.0', according to pd.__version__.

Comment: latest is `0.16.1`, might be no harm to update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file already had the header row, so no need to specify any *names*.

```
In [6]: test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=col_types)

In [7]: test
Out[7]:
       A   B  C
0  Hello  Hi  1

In [8]: test.dtypes
Out[8]:
A    object
B    object
C     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: The OP's code should not give the error suggested though no?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The error I get in pandas 0.15.2 is `cannot safely convert passed user dtype of <i8 for object dtyped data in column 2`. I just figured the OP was using a different version.

Comment: @chriscock, yes I tried there and got the same, your approach is obviously the correct one, the error just seems a bit strange.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix that error. I'd vote up your answer but I can't as I have < 15 reputation.